# Can I clone only files in a Git repository whose sizes are below a specified limit?

Tags: python, python-3.x, git, version-control

I've been tasked with scanning internal Git repositories for sensitive information (or information that should not be public).

My primary issue is that some developers have comitted large blobs (+100 MB) to their Git repositories, which takes a long time to download and are ignored for scanning purposes.

Is there any way I can tell Git to only clone files whose sizes are below a specified limit? If not, are there better ways of scanning Git repositories for sensitive information?

Comment: [This](https://git-scm.com/docs/partial-clone) came up with a cursory google search (I've never used this). I've used BFG before and git-filter branch. But never when trying to clone.

Comment: Partial clone is the only way to get what you'd like out of Git natively, and it's not entirely ready for everyday use. You may be able to get it to work for your case. Note, though, that this just means that people will sneak sensitive data into large blobs. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible with a new feature called partial clone.  You can specify a filter when cloning, and Git will limit the amount of data it fetches according to that filter.

For example, you could do the following, which would clone the Git repository without any blobs larger than 100 MiB:

```
git clone --filter=blob:limit=100m https://github.com/git/git.git
```

Note that to do this, you should use the most recent version of Git available (2.26.2) and you'll also need to have a suitable server-side implementation.  GitHub does support this, but other server implementations may or may not.

Note that even though GitHub does support partial clone, it limits the filters that are available for efficiency reasons.  Limiting blobs by size should be supported, though.

Comment: Thank you! Can you link to documentation om available filters? Could I also filter by file extension, or whether the file is a text file or not?

Comment: The filters are in [the `git rev-list` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list#Documentation/git-rev-list.txt---filterltfilter-specgt).  You cannot filter on file extension or contents.